# NSTextView paragraph style of newline

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I've been playing around with `NSTextView` and have applied some paragraph styles to certain lines. However, when I type enter and get a new line, the attributes that I applied to one line are bleeding into the next.

I want to be able to apply a paragraph style to one line and have the next line be formatted in the default way. You can see what I mean from the screenshots.

When I add some spacing between paragraphs via `NSParagraphStyle`, the same spacing applies to the newline, which makes the whole thing look pretty shotty. Basically, I am looking for a way to reset the paragraph style for an empty line.

I have tried `[MyTextView resetTypingAttributes:theAttributes]` to no avail, since you first have to start typing for the new attributes to apply. Just to be clear, the line below the text in the screenshot is the cursor, which is really far down there as a result of the paragraph spacing.

Screenshot:

---

[image: Screenshot]

---

Comment: Hello! Do you found solution to this problem ? Seems I have some problem too. :-)

Comment: I'd like to have a solution, too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to use setTypingAttributes on the textview.